# .htaccess on 2 inputs

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Right now I have the following: (this is all that is in the .htaccess file under the /page/ dir)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ set.php?numbers=$1 [QSA,L]
```

This correctly pulls with the following URL:

```
http://domain.com/location/page/XXX/
```

However, when the page loads I have the following links I want to click:

```
http://domain.com/location/page/set.php?numbers=XXX&otherset=morenumbers
```

Issue:
The other link does not seem to work because the HTACCESS rules are breaking the query strings. Is there a way around this so that the links work and that htaccess does not break it?

Comment: Show your full .htaccess and also tell where is this located?

Comment: The .htaccess is located in the /page/ dir. It also only contains that one line.

Comment: Is it required? The Rewrite rule worked so doesn't that mean it is on?

Comment: Your RewriteRule should append the original querystring via QSA flag, but I'm not understanding the link logic. If the second sample URL (presumably a link) is going to be processed by the same RewriteRule, then you would end up with a result of something like: `http://domain.com/location/page/set.php?numbers=set.php&numbers=XXX&otherset=morenumbers`

Comment: If you're needing to have the link URL pass thru without getting processed by the Rewrite, then best to add a RewriteCond above the RewriteRule. For example, `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !set.php`

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by `when the page loads I have the following links I want to click:

http://domain.com/location/page/set.php?numbers=XXX&otherset=morenumbers`